# How to concatenate multiple columns into one on Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, string-concatenation, azure-synapse

I'm trying do concat on some columns using `WHEN` condition on Azure Synapse Serverless, but there is a problem that in this new column it shows me every time only one column and the concat function doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
    Categorie, ParentGuid,
    COALESCE(CAST(EnfantGuid_7 AS nvarchar(1000)),
             CAST(EnfantGuid_6 AS nvarchar(1000)), 
             CAST(EnfantGuid_5 AS nvarchar(1000)), 
             CAST(EnfantGuid_4 AS nvarchar(1000)), 
             CAST(EnfantGuid_3 AS nvarchar(1000)), 
             CAST(EnfantGuid_2 AS nvarchar(1000)),
             CAST(EnfantGuid_1 AS nvarchar(1000))) EnfantGuid,
    CASE 
        WHEN EnfantGuid_7 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONCAT_WS(', ', CAST(EnfantGuid_1 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_2 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_3 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_4 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_5 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_6 AS nvarchar(1000)))
        WHEN EnfantGuid_6 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONCAT_WS(', ', EnfantGuid_1, EnfantGuid_2, EnfantGuid_3, EnfantGuid_4, EnfantGuid_5)
        WHEN EnfantGuid_5 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONCAT_WS(', ',EnfantGuid_1, EnfantGuid_2, EnfantGuid_3, EnfantGuid_4)
        WHEN EnfantGuid_4 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONCAT_WS(', ',EnfantGuid_1, EnfantGuid_2, EnfantGuid_3)
        WHEN EnfantGuid_3 IS NOT NULL 
            THEN CONCAT_WS(', ', CAST(EnfantGuid_2 AS nvarchar(1000)), CAST(EnfantGuid_1 AS nvarchar(1000)))
        ELSE EnfantGuid_1
    END AS [Path],  
    EnfantGuid_1, EnfantGuid_2, EnfantGuid_3
```

All columns inside the `CASE WHEN` condition are of type `UniqueIdentifier`. I tried to cast them to string as shown below but no result..

Anyone have an idea for this problem please?

Sample of result:

| Category | ParentGuid | EnfantGuid | Path | EnfantGuid_1 | EnfantGuid_2 | EnfantGuid_3 | EnfantGuid_4 | EnfantGuid_5 | EnfantGuid_6 | EnfantGuid_7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 432025b5-5a5b | 36d9d9b3-5a5b | c4cae4b5-5a5b | c4cae4b5-5a5b | 66d9d9b3-5a5b | 36d9d9b3-5a5b | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

In this row Path must contain **EnfantGuid_1** + **EnfantGuid_2** but it have only **Enfant_Guid1** ==> The last `CASE WHEN` condition

Comment: [Serverless SQL pool in Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview) is a SQL Server variant so SQL Server tag is fine IMO.

Comment: For some reason, it seems to me, that it's the 'else' part of the 'case-when' is to be executed during runtime.
Can you please change the WHEN clause just for curiosity to something always true?

Comment: I don't think so ! because when i change the order of columns like this (EnfantGuid_2,EnfantGuid_1) i found the first column so i'm sure that it execute this CASE

Answer (score 0):

Cast the datatype of **EnfantGuid_1** field in else part as varchar datatype. When new column is defined using case when statement, the datatype of the column is the datatype of expression in the **else** section.

```sql
    case when .....
        ......     
         ELSE 
            CAST(EnfantGuid_1 AS nvarchar(1000))
    END AS [Path]
```

I tried this with sample data.

```sql
create table tab1 ( v1 uniqueidentifier null, v2 uniqueidentifier null, v3 uniqueidentifier null, v4 uniqueidentifier null)
insert into tab1 values(newid(),newid(),newid(),newid());
insert into tab1 values(newid(),newid(),newid(),null);
insert into tab1 values(newid(),newid(),null,null);
select * from tab1
```

| v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d9a9b947-6c4f-47bb-b88b-d59d6e50a611 | ee3d9a9e-1b13-4189-9aa2-01a27c917cf8 | 2f0f4ae0-2251-45d2-8428-44061a6d84eb | 586df0a6-7663-4130-9bb1-e69cb61265d1 |
| 10e06207-39f6-4de1-b172-f8f42274c3fa | 0d14106c-06b7-4218-a396-574c5d48157b | fbd952ef-5364-4d87-8473-b0545cf5ed59 | null |
| 6f957995-8717-4bc7-8d75-0bd7d195a6c5 | c2128d35-5b6f-4b60-bb75-f2b4f6a28ad7 | null | null |

**Expression in Else is of uniqueidentifier type:**

```sql
select 
  case 
  when v4  is not null
   then concat_ws(', ', v1, v2, v3)
  when v3 is not null
   then concat_ws(', ', v1, v2)
  else
   v1
  end as concat_column 
from tab1
```

| concat_column |
| --- |
| d9a9b947-6c4f-47bb-b88b-d59d6e50a611 |
| 10e06207-39f6-4de1-b172-f8f42274c3fa |
| 6f957995-8717-4bc7-8d75-0bd7d195a6c5 |

**Expression in Else is of varchar  type:**

```sql
select 
  case when v4  is not null
   then concat_ws(', ', v1, v2,v3)
  when v3 is not null
   then concat_ws(', ', v1, v2)
  else
   cast(v1 as varchar(100))
  end as concat_column 
from tab1
```

| concat_column |
| --- |
| D9A9B947-6C4F-47BB-B88B-D59D6E50A611, EE3D9A9E-1B13-4189-9AA2-01A27C917CF8, 2F0F4AE0-2251-45D2-8428-44061A6D84EB |
| 10E06207-39F6-4DE1-B172-F8F42274C3FA, 0D14106C-06B7-4218-A396-574C5D48157B |
| 6F957995-8717-4BC7-8D75-0BD7D195A6C5 |